# to create variables, loops in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I create app for Android on Kotlin,I need to create 55 variables to work with them in code,how to do it using a for loop?
Variables should be look like this:
val EditText0: EditText = findViewById(R. id.et0)
val EditText1: EditText = findViewById(R. id.et1)
and so on

Answer (score 0):

When you have many of a similar kind of variable like this, you really should have a single List variable for all of them.

If they have consistent names like this, you can generate the IDs using `resources.getIdentifier`. It's easier using a List constructor than a for loop.

```
// In an Activity:
val myEditTexts: List<EditText> = List(55) { index ->
    val id = resources.getIdentifier("et$index", "id", packageName)
    findViewById<EditText>(id)
}

// In a Fragment's onViewCreated function:
val myEditTexts: List<EditText> = with(requireContext()) {
    List(55) { index ->
        val id = resources.getIdentifier("et$index", "id", packageName)
        view.findViewById<EditText>(id)
    }
}
```

If you don't want to keep all of them in a single list, then you should use [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) to let the properties be generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use getIdentifier()

```
for(int i=0; i<some_value; i++) {
   for(int j=0; j<some_other_value; j++) {
    String buttonID = "btn" + i + "-" + j;
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
    buttons[i][j] = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
    buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
   }
}
```

This is Java but same logic for kotlin.